# Using enqueueFillBuffer in openCL 2.0 produces garbage

Tags: c++, queue, buffer, opencl

I used the code below

```
 cl::Buffer intermediateBuffer = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                    distDeviceWidth * distDeviceHeight * distDeviceDepth * sizeof(T));

  cl::Event copyEvent;

  T value = 0;
   try
  {
    queue.enqueueFillBuffer(intermediateBuffer, &value, 0,
                        distDeviceWidth * distDeviceHeight * distDeviceDepth * sizeof(T),
                        NULL, &copyEvent);
  }catch (const cl::Error& error)
  {
    std::cout << "  -> Prolongation class, Problem in enqueue fill buffer" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  -> " << getErrorString(error) << std::endl;
    exit(0);
  }

  try
  {
    queue.finish();
  }catch (const cl::Error& error)
  {
    std::cout << "  -> Prolongation class, Problem in finishing fill buffer" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  -> " << getErrorString(error) << std::endl;
    exit(0);
  }
  copyEvent.wait();
```

But when I read the data from device and print it on host, The function `enqueueFillBuffer` generate garbage. I don’t know why. necessary to mention I build the data with openCL 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original `clEnqueueFillBuffer()` function in the OpenCL C API, the pattern is passed as a pair of pointer and size. In the C++ wrapper, `enqueueFillBuffer()`, the pattern is reduced to just one parameter, and it is handled as follows:

```
template<typename PatternType>
cl_int enqueueFillBuffer(
    const Buffer& buffer,
    PatternType pattern,
    ::size_t offset,
    ::size_t size,
    const VECTOR_CLASS<Event>* events = NULL,
    Event* event = NULL) const
{
    cl_event tmp;
    cl_int err = detail::errHandler(
        ::clEnqueueFillBuffer(
            object_, 
            buffer(),
            static_cast<void*>(&pattern),
            sizeof(PatternType),
```

Note how the wrapper internally takes the address-of the passed pattern data (`&pattern`) and deduces size automatically. (`sizeof(PatternType)`)

This implies that if you pass a pointer value to `enqueueFillBuffer()`, it will use *the pointer value* as the pattern, as a pointer-to-the-pointer will be passed to OpenCL. This is exactly what your code appears to be doing:

```
T value = 0;
//…
queue.enqueueFillBuffer(intermediateBuffer, &value, 0,
//               don't pass a pointer here--^^^^^^
```

Removing the `&` should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read manual for openCL but not carefully its c++ binding. That's causes the problem. But I think this kind of developing library is highly prone to make user confused.

Comment: @Mehdi_Pejvak I agree, I don’t think the C++ wrapper is very well designed. The C library seems clearer to me, and I wish the C++ wrapper just handled reference counting.